# Angular 2 Focus Form Element

Tags: angular, focus, angular2-forms

I created a form with angular 2 and now i want to add some form validation. The validation is working but now i want to focus on to the form elements. Is this possible in angular 2. What I have found so far is that I can focus an element with elementRef and Renderer i.e

```
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.el.nativeElement, 'focus');
```

But i do not want to access the element via elementRef instead I want to set the focus to one of my AbstractControl in my FormGroup object. i.e

```
this.form.controls[ controlIndex ].focus
```

is this possible with angular 2? If not how can I set the focus to the form control?

Answer (score 0):

### Current status in Angular 8

This is still not possible to do that using `ReactiveForm`. For that it is still necessary to create a dedicated directive.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[focusInvalidInput]'
})
export class FormDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('submit')
  onFormSubmit() {
    const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.ng-invalid');

    if (invalidControl) {
      invalidControl.focus();  
    }
  }
}
```

Used like that:

```
<form focusInvalidInput [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label for="first">First Name</label>
  <input formControlName="first" id="first" />

  <label for="last">Last Name</label>
  <input formControlName="last" id="last" />

  <br />
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fesawc

Answer (score -2):

An approach would be creating a directive and passing `this.form.controls[ controlIndex ].hasError` to it as parameter:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[focus-on-error]'
})
export class FocusOnErrorDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(public element: ElementRef) {}
    @Input('focusOnError') focusOnError;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // put all your focusing logic here
        // watches are also available here
        element.focus()
    }
}
```

Then on your form elements you can use it:

```
<input type="text" focus-on-error="form.controls[ controlIndex ].hasError">
```

Comment: Thanks for  your help i will try your approach today.